# Get all files in directory and subdirectory after date range

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get all the files in the directory and subdirectories after a date range?

I know that `Directory.GetFiles()` can iterate all the folders however this does not give me access to a file object in which I can do an if statement on.

Comment: It returns Full filenames with path. So the You can use Fileinfo or something to determine some file properites'

Comment: use `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()` instead of Directory and then use Linq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`File.GetCreationTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.getcreationtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and `SearchOption.AllDirectories`, for example:

```
var allFilesIn2015 = Directory.EnumerateFiles("Dir-Path", "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(path => File.GetCreationTime(path).Year == 2015)
    .ToList();
```

You could also use `FileInfo`s  and it's properties 
`CreationTime` or `LastAccessTime`:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("Dir-Path");
var allFileInfosIn2015 = dir.EnumerateFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(fi => fi.CreationTime.Year == 2015)
    .ToList();
```

I use [`EnumerateFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx) since that is more efficient in this case. It does not need to load all files into memory before it can start processing them.

Quote:

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of names
>   before the whole collection is returned; when you use GetFiles, you
>   must wait for the whole array of names to be returned before you can
>   access the array. Therefore, when you are working with many files and
>   directories, EnumerateFiles can be more efficient.