# How do we track azure file storage folder is updated or not?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, file-storage

I have azure file storage with other folders inside it.
I want to check or track when that folder is last updated ?

I have done a simple console application to get all files from that location -

```
        // Get list of all files/directories on the file share 
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageConnectionString"]);
        CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
        CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["shareName"]);

        var sourceName = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetDirectoryReference((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceName"]));
        IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = sourceName.ListFilesAndDirectories();

        CloudFileDirectory destinationDir = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetDirectoryReference((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["destinationName"]));

        foreach (IListFileItem listItem in fileList)
        {
         // gives me all file records 
        }
```

I tried to get it like this but it is `null`.
            `var test = sourceName.Properties.LastModified;`

because of null i can not able to use this query :(

```
 var latest= fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().ListFilesAndDirectories()
    .OfType<CloudFileShare>()
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Properties.LastModified)
    .ToList()
    .First();
```

> i just noticed that , i have uploaded one new file just now into that folder but still LastModified is old date , it means LastModified is separate for that folder and file :O what to do now ?
>
> I want to check whether any new file is updated into any sub-fodler of main folder or not within 24hr.

I wonder how to I check the last updated file datetime from that source folder ?

why LastModified is null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To [retrieve property values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-properties-metadata), call the `FetchAttributesAsync` method on your blob or container to populate the properties, then read the values.

When you run your console app, it essentially creates a new instance of `CloudFileShare` object and its properties are initialized to the default value. You would need to call `FetchAttributes` method on this to fill the properties.

Also, when you list the file's the properties of the file are fetched as well, you will not need to create a new instance of `CloudFileShare`. You could refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40281329/getting-null-value-for-azure-blob-last-modified-property).

You could use **sourceName.FetchAttributes();** before retrieve property. I test it and it works fine. Please refer to the code as below:

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageConnectionString"]);
CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["shareName"]);
var sourceName = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetDirectoryReference((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceName"]));
sourceName.FetchAttributes();
var test = sourceName.Properties.LastModified;
```

Comment: thanks a lot this is only giving me `LastModified` for `sourcename` i want to know if sourcename is having any subfolder which is recently updated then overall LastModified for `sourcename` should be its sub folder value.

for example - 
sourcename is having file LastModified at 11 Aug
and child folder which is inside `suourcename` is modified at 16aug 
then overall main folder value is 16aug

Comment: Yes, it will be the latest modified data.

Comment: ohh i just noticed that , i have uploaded one new file just now into that folder but still LastModified is old date , it means LastModified is separate for that folder and file :O what to do now ?

Comment: I want to check whether any new file is updated into any sub-fodler of main folder or not within 24hr.

Comment: can we use any linq query like i mentioned into question ?

Comment: You could use  `DateTime dt = File.GetLastWriteTime(path);` to get the modify data. And traverse all your file in your folder. Here is a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30185851/get-all-files-in-directory-and-subdirectory-after-date-range).

Comment: ok but in path i have Uri and it wont work here :( its azure storage

Comment: any linq query link you can suggest which will check for the latestModified property u sub-folders?

Comment: I tried linq query i posted in question but getting null because of FetchAttribute . 
How i can make it work ?

Comment: You could change `first` to`FirstOrDefault` to have a try.

Comment: did the same but it come up null , i think we need to use FetchAttributes somewhere and then filter OrderByDescending(m => m.Properties.LastModified) i tried but fail.

Comment: we need to use ListFilesAndDirectories and FetchAttributes somehow